# Are signal macros from signal.h object-like or function-like macros?

Tags: c, macros, signals, header-files

In C's [`signal.h`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/signal.h.html) header file there are a bunch of macros defined for (e.g. `SIGCONT`, `SIGKILL`).

Are these object-like macros or function-like macros?  How can one tell?

Disclaimer: very new to C programming.

Comment: The standard you reference says that _"[e]ach of the [signal constants] have distinct positive integer values."_  Does that answer your question?

Comment: What makes the difference between object-like and function-like for you? The C preprocessor is just a simple search-and-replace machine and has syntactically nothing to do with C.

Comment: @thebusybee: One difference is function-like macros can be suppressed locally by enclosing it in parentheses; `(putchar)(c)` will not be macro-replaced whereas `putchar(c)` will. Preprocessing is not simply search and replace. Even ignoring the features other than macro replacement (such as conditional inclusion, which includes evaluating expressions, or the `pragma` directive), macro replacement parses grammatical tokens as specified in the C standard and performs other computations defined **in** the C standard, not separately.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Oh, right, I forgot about that ... well ... effect, and I considered just the macro facility. However, eventhough the standard defines the preprocessor, and it happens to tokenize similarly, it still has its own syntax. The preprocessor is even a separate program in many compiler systems. So was my question: What does it make a difference on a macro as `SIGKILL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SIGCONT` and `SIGKILL` are object-like macros.

Macros that are defined and used with parenthesized arguments after them, like:

```
#define max(a, b) ((a) < (b) ? (b) : (a))
```

are function-like macros, simply because they use arguments like a function. Macros that are defined and used without parenthesized arguments, like:

```
#define c 299792458. // Speed of light / (m/s).
```

are object-like macros, because they are more like ordinary variables (which designate *objects* in the terminology of the C standard).